# How do I use return statement in these if statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

*other functions(above)*

function calculateAge(){

```
const errorDay="Days must be 1 ... 31.";
const errorMonth="Months must be 1 ... 12.";
const errorYear= "Year is too big";

let century = 0;
let bornYear= 0;
let age =0;

     bornYear=[century + idcode.substring(4,6)];

     age = (current_year-bornYear);

    document.getElementById("age").innerHTML=age;

    if ((idcode.substring(0,2) > 31) || (idcode.substring(0,2) < 1)){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML= errorDay;
    }

   else if((idcode.substring(2,4) > 12) || (idcode.substring(2,4) < 1)){
         document.getElementById("error").innerHTML=  errorMonth;

    }

   else if(bornYear > current_year){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML= errorYear;
    }
```

}
--end of function

I want to use return statement here so that the program stops and only shows error when there is an error. It doesn't stop now, the rest of the functions continue to work while displaying the error. How do I write return statement within these if else statements? (beginner here)

Comment: Please provide the full code. Right now we do not know how to stop this as we are not sure if this logic is inside for loop or forEach loop or while loop, etc.

Comment: Your code includes no function so it’s not clear what you mean exactly... can you post a minimal reproducible code snippet?

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting to get? Detailed instructions of how to write `return;` to the end of the `if` blocks?

Comment: My bad if I was not clear. I added some more code, should be clear now..?

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding a final `else` block and moving the execution of later functions in it?

Comment: is there any way to combine if ((idcode.substring(0,2) > 31) || (idcode.substring(0,2) < 1)){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML= errorDay;
    }
and a return statement?